# uninitialized constant Payroll_Manager::Teachers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compiler-errors

I'm making a payroll system for pay salaries. I only need to choice a month, a year and press "create payrolls", and create payrolls for all the teachers

[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y64Wc.png)

I created the method "create" in payroll_controller.rb:

```
Payroll_Manager.new(params[:month], params[:year]).crear_liquidaciones_del_periodo()
```

The Payroll_Manager is in the file app/helpers/payroll_manager.rb

```
class Payroll_Manager < PayrollsController

  def initialize(month, year)
    @month = month
    @year = year
  end

  def crear_liquidaciones_del_periodo
    Teachers.each do |t|
      t.payrolls.create(@month, @year)
    end
  end
end
```

And finally, I have the codel payroll.rb

```
class Payroll < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :payroll_lines

  def period
    period = month + " " + year
  end

  validates :month, presence: true
  validates :year, presence: true

  class Payroll < ActiveRecord::Base
    #gross_total, retention_total, neto_total
    before_save :calculate_payroll

  private
    def calculate_payroll
      calculate_gross_total
      calculate_retention_total
      calculate_net_total
    end

    def calculate_gross_total
      self.gross_total = 0
      ## Concepto.where(type: 1)
      haberes = Concepts.all.select{ |c| c.type == 1 }

      haberes.each do |h|
        parametros_para_linea = {concept_id: h.id, subtotal: h.amount}
        self.payroll_line.create(parametros_para_linea)
        self.gross_total += h.amount
      end
    end

    def calculate_retention_total
      self.retention_total = 0
      ## Concepto.where(type: 0)
      retencion = Concepts.all.select{ |c| c.type == 0 }

      retencion.each do |r|
        parametros_para_linea = {concept_id: h.id, subtotal: h.amount}
        self.payroll_line.create(parametros_para_linea)
        self.retention_total += r.amount
      end
    end

    def calculate_net_total
      self.net_total = gross_total - retention_total
    end
  end
end
```

...When I click the "create payroll" button, I have the error:

> uninitialized constant Payroll_Manager::Teachers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1nB9.png)

Please, help me.

Comment: why did you take `class Payroll` twice in payroll.rb. Its required only once.

Comment: Your helper inherits from PayrollsController, and you try to instantiate it from inside PayrollsController itself, that will never work. Couple of issues: a helper should be a module, not a class; you should not use a mix of snake case and camel case (i.e. rename Payroll_Manager to PayrollManager), Teachers does not exist, most likely you meant Teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition in payroll_manager.rb should be PayrollManager, not Payroll_Manager.